# PHP RSA - Can i able to compare two encrypted values

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Am using PHP secure library 'Crypt_RSA' for encryption and decryption. Is there any way to compare one Plain Text to an Encrypted Text, whether it is same or not? Like we do for password validation (md5)?

Comment: You encrypt the data, and compare it to the already encrypted data. However md5 is a hasing method, where this would be the only method to do so. But with encrypted strings, there is always a method of decrypting..

Comment: @Xorifelse Due to random padding added to messages before encryption that is unlikely to work. It would be a terrible security flaw in encryption if I could decrypt a message just by taking a guess at what it might be. You'd be better off decrypting the encrypted text and comparing it to the plaintext.

Comment: I got your point, Am saving the encrypted data in my DB and i don't want my db to get duplicated record if the user enters the same data again. So any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to compare one Plain Text to an Encrypted Text, whether it is same or not?

You should NOT be able to do this. If you can, your RSA implementation is broken (i.e. not using padding).

> Like we do for password validation (md5)?

Oh god, why would you use MD5 for passwords? [Learn how to do it right](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).

Comment: Thanks for he link Scott, Currently i cant able to do that. Any other alternative way to do this? My bottom line is i don't want DB to get duplicated with saving the same data again and again. Am storing the data as Encrypted value, I have to stop adding the data if already exist.

Comment: "Currently i cant able to do that." Why not?